# Get value from data loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This code in controller ISP should be once printed, but in here ISP follow script looping

```
 $isp = $_POST['isp'];
            if (isset($_POST['situs'])) {
                $situs = $_POST['situs'];        
                for($i = 0; $i < count($situs); $i++)
                    {
                    $dataa['hasil'][] =(object) array('isp' => $isp, 
                                                      'situs' => $situs[$i])
                    }        
                $sumber = $this->load->view('contoh', $dataa, TRUE);
```

This result :

[image: this result and view]

Comment: elobarate more about your question

Comment: what do you want to ask from this?

Comment: What is the expected result?